# How can we add a field in a data frame to find the distance between latitude & longitude in two dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, latitude-longitude, haversine

I have two data frames with latitude and longitude coordinates.  DF #1 has all kinds of business data, as well as a column for latitude and a column for longitude.  DF #2 lists all airports around the United States, and this DF also has a column for latitude and a column for longitude.  I would like to add a column in the DF #1 to find the distance between similar lat/long coordinates.  I think the Haversine methodology will work, based on my research.  I tried the function below, but I'm getting really large numbers in my distance column.

```
lon1 = df_result['longitude_fuze']
lon2 = df_airports['longitude_air']
lat1 = df_result['latitude_fuze']
lat2 = df_airports['latitude_air']

from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km

# Creating a new column to generate the output by passing lat long information to Haversine Equation
df_result['distance'] = [haversine(df_result.longitude_fuze[i],df_result.latitude_fuze[i],df_airports.longitude_air[i],df_airports.latitude_air[i]) for i in range(len(df_result))]
df_result['distance'] = df_result['distance'].round(decimals=3)
# Printing the data table 
df_result.head()
df_result
```

Here isn a small screen shot my my DF with the distance column calculated, presumably by the difference between the lat/long in the two dataframes.

[image]

What could be wrong here?  I would expect the distances to be very small, or if distances are quite large, maybe I need a different approach, like if the distance is >1 mile, do nothing and skip to the next row to check the next distance.  Any idea what could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: The distance calculated in kilometers seems reasonable to me. LA and San Francisco are 740km apart.

Comment: I would like to add a column in the DF #1 to find the distance between SIMILAR lat/long coordinates, and calculate the distance between those. For instance, if DF#1 has a lat/long coordinate that is <1 mile from a lat/long coordinate in DF#2, this is SIMILAR, and I can identify this as an airport in DF#1. Similarly, if DF#1 has a lat/long coordinate that is >1 mile from a lat/long coordinate in DF#2, this is NOT SIMILAR, and I can identify this as a NON airport in DF#1. I want to set a flag, based on the distance between lat/long coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried importing from NumPy instead of standard math?